# cross_val_score does not take into account scoring parameter

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

could you please help me to explain why `cross_val_score` from scikit learn does not take into account `scoring` parameter? I must be doing something wrong and I really cannot find what.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score
from sklearn import svm

data = load_iris()

precisions = cross_val_score(svm.SVC(), data['data'], data['target'], cv=4, scoring="precision_micro") 
recalls = cross_val_score(svm.SVC(), data['data'], data['target'], cv=4, scoring="recall_micro") 
accuracies = cross_val_score(svm.SVC(), data['data'], data['target'], cv=4, scoring="accuracy") 

print(precisions)
print(recalls)
print(accuracies)
```

Returns:

```
[ 0.97435897  1.          0.94444444  0.97222222]
[ 0.97435897  1.          0.94444444  0.97222222]
[ 0.97435897  1.          0.94444444  0.97222222]
```

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html mentions the iris dataset is (almost) balanced across classes so some scores are the same

Comment: Change the recall_micro, precision_micro to others like recall_macro, recall_weighted etc, and you will see the difference